# How to submit a form from another component outside of the form container Vue

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a form on my page which I wish to trigger the submit from another button outside of the form how can I do this?

Comment: please share the code

Comment: There are plenty of one lined questions on SO that are relevant. Like this one.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add a ref to the HTML form

```
<form ref="form">
  <input name="field" v-model="value">
</form>
```

Then inside your methods you can use the reference to submit the form

```
methods: {
  send: function(){
    this.$refs.form.submit()
  }
}
```

and you can call the send method wherever your want.

You can learn more about ref attribute here

https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-template-refs.html